# When I query the Instagram public_content api for the username nasa, the returned results are for username nasagoddard

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I wrote a small app to query the Instagram public_content api and everything works perfectly. I've been able to successfully download all data from several different usernames. However, I have attempted to query with the username "nasa" and the results which are returned are for the username "nasagoddard." Why would this be the case?

Comment: show what you have coded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of searching for "nasa", I searched for "@nasa" and the correct result was returned.

Answer (score 2):

When you search for `nasa` using Instagram User search API, it returns about 25 similar username, `nasagoddard` is at top, and then `nasa` is second, they order search results by popularity of accounts, so you cannot assume the username you search is the first results, you have to iterate thru the results and compare/pick the username that matches your search. and then get photos for that user_id.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching usernames for user_id. User ids are always unique and should work

To get an id from a username use this tool: https://smashballoon.com/instagram-feed/find-instagram-user-id/